# how get value of javascript dynamically added text field

Tags: javascript, text, field

I wrote the following code to create the required fields. But I can not send a fields value.

Named fields within the Javascript code do. I want to send through PHP, but I can not.

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var side = document.glass.side.value;
var angle = document.glass.side.value - 1;
var x="";
for (var i=0;i<side;i++)
{
x=x + 'طول ضلع '+(i+1)+' : <input type="text" name="sl'+(i+1)+'"  class="textfield" style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:4px; padding-right:0px; height:18px; width:77px; font-size:12px;"  size="32"/>' + ' <span class="style3">سانتی متر</span><br>';
}
document.getElementById("sideview").innerHTML=x;
var y="";
for (var i=0;i<angle;i++)
{
y=y + 'اندازه زاویه '+(i+1)+' : <input type="text" name="angle'+(i+1)+'" class="textfield" style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:4px; padding-right:0px; height:18px; width:77px; font-size:12px;"  size="32"/>' + ' <span class="style3">درجه</span><br>';
}
document.getElementById("angleview").innerHTML=y;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To send it through PHP you have to send the form by the user clicking a button to submit the form. The form needs to be sent by `GET` or `POST`. The page will refresh and then you can get the query link variables by PHP.